# How to search and filter on multiple related models?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an search and filter system in which user can type and search related courses and institutions. This is my model structure:

Model Structure:

```
    Institutions:
     - Name
     - Id
     - email
     - address
    ...... etc.

    Courses:
     - owner = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     - name
     - ref
     - license
     - overview

..... etc
```

Now by using the above, i have created a search bar in which user needs to type something and then press "search" button or else press "Enter" key. This will show search results. My search code:

```
query = request.GET.get('q')
courses = Course.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
institution= Institution.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)

queryset_chain = chain(courses,institution)
```

So the problem here is that, I want to display the result as follows.

**scenario 1:**

Lets say that course and Institution has same name like "tech".

When user search for "tech", I need to show result as follows:

---

Institution Name

- Course name

---

**scenario 2:**

Lets say that course has name as "tech" but not Institution has that name.

When user search for "tech", I need to show result as follows:
In this case, I need to show the Course name and also correspondant Institution
name:

---

Institution Name

- Course name

---

**scenario 3:**

where Institution has "tech" as name. But no course
name.

---

Institution Name

- any random Course name

---

How to handle this kind of clubbed search and filter ?

Comment: What will you return for courses on 3rd scenario? All courses of that institution or let's say the first one?

Comment: Just first one or any random one ! @ÇağatayBarın

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot replicate your app, I can only give you an idea of how to solve this. `Course` model is the child of the `Institution` model, you can apply `prefetch_related()` or `select_related()` to prevent N+1 queries. These codes sum up all three scenarios using the `Q()` object from Django since you can use the OR -> `|` expression on it.

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = request.GET.get('q')
courses = Course.objects.select_related('institution') \
                        .filter(Q(institution_set__name__icontains=query) |
                                Q(course_set__name__icontains=query))
```

You also don't need to use `chain`, try [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). I'm not sure what result you expect for the third scenario, but maybe adding the condition will do good.

Comment: For third scenario, i need to show any random course !

Comment: I think this is a really good answer to start. @christine11 I'd suggest you to play with it and don't be afraid to make another query for your needs. There isn't always that PERFECT query which will solve all your questions, so sometimes you have to improvise and use multiple queries to solve your problem.